# Focus handling for async behaviour - do not steal already set focus

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, focus

**[introduction]** I have sample WPF application. If I click a button, new window is opened. I need to wait some time for data to be loaded inside it. Rather than passively wait, I want to do some other stuff in the meantime. I can for example open some context menu. This situation is illustrated on the screen below:

[image]

This wait-for-me window, just after the loading is completed (data is ready to show), fires an event where focus is set to the grid:

```
void DataLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{             
    grid.Focus();
    grid.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

**[current issue]** Unfortunately, in the very same moment, our recently opened context menu has just disappeared. The focus has been forcefully stolen from it. Annoying final effect is shown below:

[image]

**[desired effect]** What would be the happy end? It would be no automatic focus, if user just changed it to any other element (like context menu). In the other words - do not steal the focus.

[image]

The code modification could be:

```
void DataLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Magic.FocusNotChanged)
    {                
        grid.Focus();
        grid.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

But, what is the **Magic**? Some global publish subscribe mechanism which allows or denies automatic focus changes? Some handler which is spying focus changes?

BTW: This particular application shown above is just artificially extracted from much wider context. Do not pay much attention to the layout implemented here. Some generic mechanism has to be invented, not related to this specific button or context menu. Any clues?
Regards.

Comment: Only thing that pops to my mind is checking if the current focus is still on the button when processing the event handler for data loaded. Assuming that is 'no other focus actions done by the user'

Comment: @Marvin Smit: It's not an option I think. While the event handler is fired, the empty window is already opened from some time. So the focus do not exists on the button anymore. It's long gone as far as I understand focus. What's more, a button is just an example. The window could be opened in some other way e.g by context menu, which disappears just after menu item is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is prosaic - to take focus in a non-invasive way, check if window is active that time:

```
void DataLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsActive)
    {                
        grid.Focus();
        grid.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

*Some further enhancements:*

Suppose we'd like to have more generic solution. What if we want to set the focus from within particular control hosted by some window, not from the window itself (lack of `IsActive` property)? We need to find its parent window, to check if it is still active. What's more, let's suppose this control contains a bunch of child controls, and we would like to set focus to some particular child. Look at this:

```
void DataLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var window = this.GetParent<Window>();
    if (window.IsActive)
    {         
        var grid = this.GetChild<DataGrid>();
        grid.Focus();
    }
}
```

You can see the usage of two helper methods. Their implementation is given below:

```
public static T GetParent<T>(this DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (child == null) return null;

    // get parent item
    var parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    // we’ve reached the end of the tree
    if (parentObject == null) return null;
    // check if the parent matches the type we’re looking for
    var parent = parentObject as T;
    // return parent if match or use recursion to proceed with next level
    return parent ?? GetParent<T>(parentObject);            
}

public static T GetChild<T>(this DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (parent == null) return null;
    T result = null;

    var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var childObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        var child = childObject as T;
        if (child == null)
            result = childObject.GetChild<T>();
        else
        {
            result = (T) childObject;
            break;
        }
    }   
    return result;
}
```